# Not to close on esc or by clicking outside of the dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, dialog

Currently, for my own project, I am using the following library or plugin (which one you called it) for pop up, it is way a great plugin, I really like that, but one thing that I want to modify is to not to close the dialog box on pressing the esc key or by clicking outside of the dialog box.

I already look at the JQuery UI.js file and there is a variable called closeOnEscape and a bunch of function logic to handle closeOnEscape on the dialog.

Is there any way that I can implement to modify like closeOnEscape to this great library or plugin? as well as not to close by clicking outside of the dialog box.

Here is the link:

[Dialog](https://github.com/tornqvist/dialog)

[JS File](https://github.com/tornqvist/dialog/blob/master/jquery.dialog.js)

First of all, sorry to not post any codes or whatsoever.

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: add `closeOnEscape: false,`

Comment: There is a inbuilt  escape : true, setting in your js at line 25. set it to false

Comment: Wow, I didn't see there is a `escape` variable at line 25 on that JS plugin. Thanks to pointed that out @Manjoor. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  $(document).on('keydown', function(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode === 27) {
      ev.preventDefault();
  }
  });



$(document).on('click', function(ev) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('you outside box class')) {
          ev.preventDefault();
      }
  });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Alex Berd, thanks for stopping by, but I have tried your solution for clicking outside of the dialog box, as I didn't have the class "you outside box class", what should I replace it by? As for the `escape` key, I am using `escape` variable defined from `escape: true` to `escape: false`.

Comment: I will ask you a question: when you want to close you window? May be you have any buttons, divs, labels etc., that when you have event action on them you window is closed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property  called 
escape      : true,

I assume you could set this to false

or in the actual plug in look for and change its function

```
if (key_code === 27) {
        $[prefix]('close');
}
```

and change it to

```
//   if (key_code === 27) {
//        $[prefix]('close');
//   }
```

That should disable the Escape Key

Comment: Hi @Lawrence Edel, thanks for stopping by, I changed it to `escape: false` from `escape: true`, in case I want to modify later on back to `true`.